# Problema con toString para devolver un objeto con formato en Java

Tags: java

tengo un problema con un programa en Java. Es un programa para generar tickets de compra. El problema lo tengo en la clave que genera el toString() con formato para devolver el ticket.
El código es este:

```
public String toString() {//Arreglar...
        String formato="\n%s: %s \n%s: \n%s \t%s \t%s \t%s ";
        String lista="Nombre Precio Unidades Importe";
        for (Iterator<Producto> it = listaCompra.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Producto producto = (Producto) it.next();
            formato+="\n%s \t%.2f€ \t%d \t%.2f€ ";
            lista+= producto.getNombre()+producto.getPrecio()+producto.getUnidades()+producto.calcularImporte();
        }
        formato +="\n%s: \n%s: %.2f";
        return String.format(formato, "Venta con código", this.codigoVenta,"Productos de la lista de la compra",lista,"El importe total de la compra es",calcularImporte());
        //return "\nVenta con código: "+ this.codigoVenta + "\nProductos de la lista de la compra: "+ lista+ "\nEl importe total de la compra es:"+
    //calcularImporte()+"€";
    }
```

Debería quedar así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Muchas gracias y siento las molestias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) alguna de las respuestas cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Y recuerda además mencionar _cuál es/era el problema_: otras personas podrían tener el mismo problema, y no llegarán a tu pregunta si se titula "problema con..." ni describes el problema en cuestión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes aplicar String format a los encabezados dentro de una cadena,es por eso que quizá te marca un error

```
String lista="Nombre Precio Unidades Importe";
```

lo que puedes hacer es manejar los encabezados en un arreglo y darles formato

```
String [] titulo={"Nombre", "Precio","Unidades","Importe"};

        String lista=String.format("\n%s \t\t%s \t\t%s \t%s",titulo[0],titulo[1],titulo[2],titulo[3]);
    
        String format="\n%s \t%.2f \t\t%d \t\t%.2f";

          for(Producto producto:listaCompra){

            lista+=String.format(format,producto.getNombre(),producto.getPrecio(),producto.getUnidades(),producto.calcularImporte());
        
        }
      
        return lista;
```

Ejemplo de salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has solucionado el problema, te lo agradezco mucho C;

Comment: @AlexandruCristianIordache si la respuesta te ha sido de ayuda, marca la respuesta como aceptada dando click en el check.

Answer (score 0):

una vez solucionada la duda con las respuestas aportadas por la comunidad lo que mejorado y terminado tal que así, por si le sirve de algo a alguien:

```
public String toString() {
        String lista=String.format("\n|%-20s| |%-21s| |%-20s| |%-21s|","Nombre", "Precio","Unidades","Importe");

        for (Iterator<Producto> it = listaCompra.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Producto producto = (Producto) it.next();
            lista+=String.format("\n|%20s| |%20.2f€| |%20d| |%20.2f€|",producto.getNombre(),producto.getPrecio(),producto.getUnidades(),producto.calcularImporte());
        }
        lista+=String.format("\n|%68s: %20.2f€|","Costo total",calcularImporte() );
        return "\nVenta con código: "+ this.codigoVenta +
                "\n***********************Productos de la lista de la compra************************************"+
                lista + 
                "\n*********************************************************************************************"; 
    }
```

Quedaría así el formato:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]